# Binary Polar vs 4-PAM Signalling

Tags: bandwidth, baseband, polar

Why is binary polar signalling not feasible for a data rate of 2.0Mbps within a bandwidth not exceeding 1MHz?

Is it due to the fact that binary signalling can only transfer 1 bit of data per symbol thus, a 1MHz bandwidth would not be large enough for the given data rate?

Then a 4-PAM signal would carry 2 bits of information per symbol which would be more appropriate?

Comment: I believe you got that right, so can you narrow down the question to exactly where your doubt comes from?

Comment: And keep in mind that it is theoretically possible to achieve that rate, if you use sinc pulses.